# AWS::Serverless::Function Won't work with "InlineCode" property

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I try to create, using SAM CLI, inline Lambda function code.

I have the following template for my Inline function:

```yaml
    HealthFunction:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
            PackageType: Zip
            Runtime: nodejs20.x
            Handler: index.handler
            InlineCode: |
                export const handler = (event) => {
                    return { statusCode: 200 };
                }
            Timeout: 30
            Description: 'Health Lambda function'
            Events:
                Api:
                    Type: HttpApi
                    Properties:
                        ApiId: !Ref AwsApiGateway
                        Path: /health
                        Method: GET
```

And I just run `sam local start-api`. Then I get an error:

```
Initializing the lambda functions containers.
Lambda functions containers initialization failed because of expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Error: Lambda functions containers initialization failed
```

It seems like SAM wants `CodeUri` property (I assume?), but according to documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-inlinecode

It is OK to keep `CodeUri` empty as long as `InlineCode` is defined.

So where is the problem here?